# How to not wait for code to be executed before going to the next element in array in for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say i have a jquery foreach

```js
$(".myClassName").each(function(){
  // do stuff that takes 3 seconds to be executed
  doStuff();

})
```

how can i make it so that it dsnt wait for doStuff() to be finnished before executing that code for the next element.

i bascilly want doStuff() to be executed all at the same time, for each element

Comment: Maybe web workers https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp can help you out.

Comment: Don't write functions that take 3s to execute. What kind of heavy processing are you doing?

Comment: its an animation, i want this code to last 3 seconds

Comment: An animation should be asynchronous, and starting three asynchronous tasks in that loop will already run them concurrently. Just don't use a blocking `sleep` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution,
if you wrap doStuff() in a setTimeout it will work,

this is because setTimeout dsnt pause the code for x amount, it will delay the code for x amount

:)

Comment: If it is the same animation for all the elements, you could also make an unique animation that triggers on all the elements at the same time, like for example: `$(".myClassName").fadeIn("slow")`. This will fade-in all the elements with class **myClassName**.